# Difference between NFC Forum Tag 2 and Mifare Ultralight from developers perspective?

Tags: nfc, standards

I read someplace that **Mifare ultralight** was ALMOST the same as **NFC Forum Tag 2**, but not quite. So what is the difference between them?

Can I use the same `libnfc` commands to access them for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFC Forum are specification.
Mifare Ultralight is a product.

Mifare Ultralight is compatible with NFC Forum Type 2 Tag.

Here a usefull document to summarize:
http://open-nfc.org/documents/PRE_NFC_0804-250%20NFC%20Standards.pdf